# debug application by running .sh file using eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, sh

I have a .sh file which runs independently on Linux server to sync some data but now there is some problem with the sync so I wanted to run this .sh file in debug mode in eclipse so that I can check my java code where the problem is?

Is there any plugin or options available in eclipse to do this.

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `debug` your java code which your shell script invokes, just write a wrapper java code which invokes your `main` java code, and you can easily debug using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of this .sh file? Is it running a JAR?

If so, you can remotely debug a java code. The following blog explains using screenshots: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think we can use shell script debugger in the Java debugger session. i.e you need to debug java code and shell script code separately in separate debug sessions.

You can use [basheclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/basheclipse/) to debug shell script, this will only work with shell script editor [ShellEd](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/shelled/wiki).

Also check the open tickets for debugging in ShellEd.

Note
Outside eclipse you can try http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/